# Running native query at mongodb from RestService

Tags: java, mongodb, rest

I have a little test setup, running mongodb and a restful service at server side. The service provides a small website. What I'd like to do now is using the devtools, sending a command over to the backend 
Something like

```
mongo.run("db.collection.find({})");
```

This command should be received by my own Rest service, forwarded to the mongodb and it should return the values as json. (Should work with any kind of query)

Essentially, I want to be able to run any command, I'll send to the server as a string. (Don't you worry, it's just for my test setup)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are able to send `collection name` from client, you can try the following code: (Just a thought, not tested the code)

```
var func = req.body.queryToRun;
var res = runQuery(func);
console.log(res);

function runQuery(query)
{
   var resultQuery = query.split('"')[0]; //
   return resultQuery;
}
```

Comment: ?? I guess you didn't understand my question. I want a way to simply forward a string (which will be a query) to mongodb and I want the result (as json)

Comment: `req.body.queryToRun` will be the query as a string, that you will send from client with the request. Do you want to know how to send from client?